# Get exception content in Rails Router

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, exception, airbrake

So I handle exceptions with an error controller to display dynamic content to my users in production. I have it in my route file to do:

```
  # Errors
  %w( 404 422 500 ).each do |code|
    get code, :to => "errors#show", :code => code
  end
```

The only problem is now that I'm routing on errors such as that I lose information in my controller when I want to notify Airbrake. How can I maintain the exception information and send it to Airbrake on a 500? Right now all I get is the env that was occurring at the time of the exception which is less helpful for debugging purposes.

```
class ErrorsController < ApplicationController

  def show
    notify_airbrake(env) 
    render status_code.to_s, :status => status_code
  end

  protected

  def status_code
    params[:code] || 500
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you handling an error by redirecting to a URL like `http://your.site/500`? That will be just an HTTP request like any other, losing the exception context you're after. Instead, you probably want to be using `ActionController`'s [Rescue](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#rescue) functionality. It would look like this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  rescue_from StandardError, with: :render_error

  private

  def render_error(error)
    notify_airbrake(error)
    render text: 500, status: 500
  end
end
```

You can add multiple `rescue_from` declarations to handle different kinds of error, like the `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` from the Rails guide's example.